# How to find "empty button"?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I'm using the WAVE tool for accessibility testing. It logged an error "empty button". I tried finding the error using WAVE.

```
finding for input tag having type="button" or "submit" but not value
button tag having no text
```

I did not find any of the mentioned elements. Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the page in question?

Comment: How can we help you find the error if you don't post the code you ran through your accessibility app?

Answer (score 2):

When WAVE says "finding for input tag having type="button" or "submit" but not value
button tag having no text" it means:

1. You have a input button without a value, like this:

Is wrong:

```
<input type="button">
```

Without a value, the user with screen reader can't understand the purpose of input. So you should give it a value indicating the action, like this:

Is right:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit">
```

2. It is the same with a tag button without a text:

Is wrong

```
<button></button>
```

Is right:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: Oh that's true, @Rob! Thank you! I already adjusted it.

Answer (score 1):

(Based on what you told so far.)
A button can be represented by:

- an `INPUT` element with the `type` attribute set to `button` or `submit`;
- a `BUTTON` element.

An `INPUT`-based button’s text is represented by its `value` attribute.

A `BUTTON`-based button’s text is its text content which, in static HTML, is text between the start (`<button>`) and end (`</button>`) tags.